# Unsupported get request only when using app token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When requesting `/703889222997557` via the Facebook Graph API, I am receiving the error "Unsupported get request." But this only occurs when using an app token. When I use the "standard token" you get when opening the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), the request is successful. As soon as select an App in the Explorer and use the App Token, the request fails again.

Any ideas what the problem might be here?

Comment: This is the post in question: https://www.facebook.com/siegerbrauckmann/photos/pcb.703896506330162/703889222997557/ As far as I can tell, it is public and the page is not requested (no alcohol and so on).

Comment: I don't believe you need an access token for this since the information is available to the public.

Comment: That may be so. But I should still be able to access public information even with an access key.

Comment: It may not be designed to accept an access token if its not required.  Perhaps try requesting a field that does require an access token and see if it works then.  If not, its possibly a bug or the wrong access token.